# Write to stderr in response to Console.CancelKeyPress when redirecting stdout

Tags: c#, .net

When I run the program below and hit `ctrl+C` it writes nothing when stdout is redirected.

```
> .\ConsoleApplication2.exe
Cancelled by user.
> .\ConsoleApplication2.exe > foo.txt
>
```

Is there a work-around for this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }

        static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Cancelled by user.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it with your code. It still writes "Cancelled by user." to the console when I press ctrl-c and redirecting with "> foo.txt".

Comment: @Dirk Are you using Powershell or cmd.exe? It seems to work when I use cmd.exe. Maybe this is a Powershell bug.

Comment: I was using cmd.exe console.

Comment: Using powershell I can reproduce it. But from the documentation I just read stderr should only be redirected when using "2>".

Comment: I too cannot reproduce - copied and compiled your code exactly. You may want to test the `Console.IsErrorRedirected` property and see if that sheds any light on things.